# After Codeigniter Redirect, multi curl is pending forever.

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, curl

I am using codeigniter, then i redirect after delete action.
this my script for delete

```
if ($this->input->post('chkv')) {
                $id = $this->uri->segment(4); 
              $this->md_distributor->deletesite();
              redirect('admin/distributor/menulist/2/'.$id);
```

in this controller there is 3 curl , this my curl request

```
  function getROprovince()
   {

    $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "https://pro.xxxxx.com/api/province",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "key: xxxxxxx"
          ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
          return json_decode($response)->rajaongkir->results;

        }      



   }
```

second curl

```
function getROCity($province)
   {

    $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "https://pro.xxxxx.com/api/city?province=".$province,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "key: xxxxx"
          ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
          return json_decode($response)->rajaongkir->results;

        }      



   }
```

third curl

```
   function getROKec($city)
   {

    $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "https://pro.xxxxx.com/api/subdistrict?city=".$city,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "key: xxxxxx"
          ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            //echo $response;
         return json_decode($response)->rajaongkir->results;

        }      



   }
```

if just using location.href= it doesnt matter.
because first load using  location.href and not problem

but when after delete action i am using redirect then only execute one curl, and it is randomly .

please advise.

Comment: you show 3 functions, none of which are ever called in your first code nor does there seem to be an explanation for how all these functions are used. also your timeout is 30 seconds.

Comment: as i said , in this 'admin/distributor/menulist/2/'.$id it contains 3 curl, if i explain all code it will be long description. then first load there is no problem , just 1-5 seconds for execute all curl.

Comment: whether or not the controller contains 1500 functions, if you are posting them here you should explain how they relate. right now it only makes sense to you. anyways chances are some queries are taking longer than others. you'd have to narrow it down.